# How to pass DR extract query filter values dynamically to DR/IP when calling through action

Tags: omnistudio, vlocity

I've a dataraptor which is querying multiple sobjects and in one of the query, there's an offset filter
[image]
﻿There's also a formula in the DR, which gives the next offset value and this value is being passed to the flexcard and I can see it in the flexcard build fields when I fetch the dataraptor
[image][image]

I've a flexcard which is using this dataraptor and child flexcards, lwc's to display the information as below[image]
﻿The arrow shown is an image which has action added to it. [image]
﻿

I'm passing the offset value manually everytime through the action to get the new values. How can I pass the offset filter value dynamically when calling the DR through action? I've the nextoffset value which is coming from the dataraptor but I'm not sure how to pass it as value to the offset filter

Comment: I think it is not possible to pull the offset value from a formula. It can be a node from the input JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically provide the `offset` value in your action by using merge fields (see Salesforce help [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_access_flexcard_data_json_with_merge_fields.htm&type=5)).

If the data source of your Flexcard outputs the `varNextOffset` value, then you can reference it in your action using a merge field such as `{varNextOffset}`.
The JSON path in curly brackets needs to be the JSON path to your property in the Flexcard JSON.

Good luck!